# Compact kernel operator on $L^p$ space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces, compact-operators

> Let $\displaystyle U_1 \subset \mathbb R^{n_1}$ and $\displaystyle U_2
>  \subset \mathbb R^{n_2} $ measurable sets, $\displaystyle 1 < p,q <
>  \infty $ and consider the measurable function $\displaystyle K:U_1
>  \times U_2 \to \mathbb R $ with $$\displaystyle \|K\|= \left(
>  \int_{U_1} \Big( \int_{U_2} |\,K(x,y) |^{p^{'}} dy  \Big)^{q/p^{'}}
> dx \right)^{1/q} < \infty ,$$  where $\displaystyle \frac{1}{p} +
>  \frac{1}{p^{'}} =1$.
>
> Prove that the operator $T:\displaystyle L^p (U_2) \to L^q (U_1) $, with
>   $\displaystyle (Tf)(x)= \int_{U_2} K(x,y) f(y) dy $,  is compact.

I tried to prove it by the definition of the compact operator but I didn't made it. Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: Can you give more details about what you tried, and where you got stuck?

Comment: @NateEldredge: I am not sure how to start, I tried to take the image of the unit ball through $T$ and prove that this is relatively compact, but I do not know how to write it down. If you could give me some hints that would be great. Thanking in advance.

Comment: The assumption says that $K$ belongs to (i.e. can be identified in a canonical way with an element of) the Lebesgue-Bochner space $X=L^q(U_1, L^{p'}(U_2))$. Prove first that the operator has finite rank if $K$ is a simple function (as a member of $X$). Then approximate.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, there were very helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints.

1. $K(x,y)$ can be approximated in its operator norm by sums of the form $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i(x)b_i(y)$, where $a_i\in L^q(U_1)$ and $b_i\in L^{p'}(U_2)$.
2. If $K(x,y)$ is replaced by $a_i(x)b_i(x)$, where $a_i\in L^q(U_1)$ and $b_i\in L^{p'}(U_2)$,
   then the resulting operator is of rank $1$, and hence compact, while if $K$ is
   replaced by   $K_N(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^N a_i(x)b_i(y)$, where $a_i\in L^q(U_1)$ and $b_i\in L^{p'}(U_2)$, then resulting operator is of rank $N$, and hence again compact. If $\|K_N-K\|\to 0$, then $K$ should be compact as the limit of compact operators.